# CoreBluetooth central not dicovering any peripheral when specifying service

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to figure out how to use CoreBluetooth to scan for peripherals advertising a service known in advance. So I have the following view controller that shows discovered peripherals in a UITableViewController:

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var discoveredPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
    var connectedPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
    var peripheralsSupportingDeviceInformation = [CBPeripheral]()

    private let scannedServices: [CBUUID]? = [CBUUID(string: "180A")]//nil

    private var scanning = false

    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return discoveredPeripherals.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let peripheral = discoveredPeripherals[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = peripheral.identifier.uuidString
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = peripheral.name ?? ""
        if self.peripheralsSupportingDeviceInformation.contains(peripheral) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func scanTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if !scanning {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(scanTapped(_:)))
            self.discoveredPeripherals.removeAll()
            self.connectedPeripherals.removeAll()
            self.peripheralsSupportingDeviceInformation.removeAll()
            self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Scan", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(scanTapped(_:)))
            self.centralManager?.stopScan()
            self.centralManager = nil
        }

    }
}

extension MasterViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: scannedServices, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false])
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if discoveredPeripherals.contains(where: { periph -> Bool in
            periph.identifier.uuidString == peripheral.identifier.uuidString
        }) {
            return
        }
        self.discoveredPeripherals.append(peripheral)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.connectedPeripherals.append(peripheral)
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(scannedServices)
    }
}

extension MasterViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Service discovery error: \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            if let services = peripheral.services, services.contains(where: { service -> Bool in
                service.uuid.uuidString == "180A"
            }) {
                self.peripheralsSupportingDeviceInformation.append(peripheral)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else if let services = peripheral.services {
                let serviceList = services.map { service -> String in
                    return service.uuid.uuidString
                }
                print("Services supported by \(peripheral.description): \(serviceList.joined(separator: ", "))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is as basic as can be, and I don't have anything else in my application for now.
Now if I set `scannedServices` to `nil`, I get all the devices around me, and most of them, like my MacBook Pro, my Apple Watch and so on show a checkmark indicating that the advertise the Device Information service (180A).
Yet when I set scannedServices to `[CBUUID(string: "180A")]` to scan only for devices that advertise this service (at least that's what I understood from the documentation), then the `centralManager(_:didDiscover:,advertisementData:,RSSI:)` delegate method is never called anymore and the list remains empty.

Did I forget something or misinterpret something in the documentation?
If you want to give it a try, the full project is [there](https://github.com/sarbogast/BluetoothScanner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. The reason for not discovering any devices is different...

Even though most Bluetooth devices implement the *Device Information* service, they do not advertise it. When your app scans for devices, the filter works on the advertisement data. So no devices are found. Once you have connected to a device, all implemented service will be available.

So you need to test with a different Bluetooth service that is indeed advertised. The MacBook Pro does not advertise any service unless you have an application running that does so. I don't know about the Apple Watch. Possibly you need another device for your test.

Install the *nRF Connect* app from Nordic Semiconductor on an Android or iOS device. It can scan for peripheral and display the advertised services. It can even configure it as a peripheral by selecting and advertising services.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, that's what I was afraid of. I wish this distinction was more clearly documented but I get it now. So the filter matches the values advertised in key CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey of the advertisement data I receive, right?